# Serilog: Logging different types of log events

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

My API is accessed by different types of consumers. There are external applications, and users via web interface.

I'll try to explain with an example:
So in a method call, I'd like to log who or what accessed it.

In case of external application, I'd like to log something like this (using template):

```
"[{Caller}] {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] (RequestId:{RequestId} | Key:{Key} | AppVersion:{Version}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

and in case of user triggered action, I'd like to log something like:

```
"[{Caller}] {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] FullName:{FullName} | Organization:{Organization} | AppVersion:{Version}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Both types of method callers are accessed from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`, but each implements different type of identity, with different custom properties.

My code would look like:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    Log.Information("DoSomething called");
}
```

If I have logger configured with something like:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                   .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", appVersion)
                   .Enrich.WithProperty("Caller", caller)
                   .Enrich.With(new MyEnricher())
                   .WriteTo.ColoredConsole(outputTemplate: "[{Caller}] {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] FullName:{FullName} | Organization:{Organization} | AppVersion:{Version}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                   .CreateLogger();
```

it would never display Key and RequestId, if called triggered by external application (thread identity).

I added `MyEnricher` to the logger, and is something like:

```
public class MyEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
        if (identity is ExternalIdentity)
        {
            var externalIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ExternalIdentity;
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Key", externalIdentity.Key));
            logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("RequestId", externalIdentity.RequestId));
        }
        else
        {
            var userIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as UserIdentity;

            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("FullName", userIdentity.FullName));
            logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Organization", userIdentity.OrganizationName));
        }
}
```

As far as I've been able to grasp from documentation and examples online, logging template is set only in the moment of configuring logger, before its actual creation. I could not access and modify template in enricher via LogEvent as it is read-only (has getter only).

I'm aware of possible message formatting, but this is not what I'm looking for in this particular case.

The end result I'd like to see in logs, for external app access is something like:

> 17 Jan 2016 10:11:42.524  [API] 10:11:40 [Information] (RequestId: 123 | Key: XXX-1 | AppVersion:1.2.1) DoSomething called

and when logged for the user:

> 17 Jan 2016 11:12:42.524  [WEB] 11:12:40 [Information] (FullName: Anonymous | Organization: MyOrg | AppVersion:1.2.1) DoSomething called

My question is: how (if possible) can I log (and see it in the logs) different types of events with different properties to log in template? Is it possible to manipulate the template in run-time on the fly? I would not like to have template with all possible tokens from both or many other possible event types, and their properties defined in one place (having many of them blank in one case or the other).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can accept slightly different formatting from your example, you might use destructuring here:

`"[{Caller}] {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] ({Principal}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"`

Then in your enricher:

```
public class MyEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
        if (identity is ExternalIdentity)
        {
            var externalIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ExternalIdentity;
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Principal", new {
                externalIdentity.Key,
                externalIdentity.RequestId
            }, true));
        }
        else
        {
            var userIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as UserIdentity;
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("Principal", new {
                userIdentity.FullName,
                userIdentity.OrganizationName
            }, true));
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the `true` to trigger serialization of the anonymous objects.)

This will output the various properties of the principal in a key-value pair syntax.

Otherwise, using a custom `ITextFormatter` to do it (basing the code on Serilog's `DisplayFormatter`) is the way to go. `ColoredConsole` won't accept a custom text formatter, but:

```
WriteTo.Sink(new RollingFileSink(@"Logs\app-{Date}.txt", formatter))
```

will allow one to be passed through.